# Adding private git source with key is automatically removed when run a workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have workflow that creates application for linux and windows and then publish them as release, like:

```
name: Build x64

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
    tags:
    - 'v*'
    
env:
  version: 1.0.1
  

jobs:
  build_linux:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.x
    - name: Add organization git
      run: dotnet nuget add source --username MY_USER --password PASSWORD_PAT_GENERATED_FROM_MY_PROFILE_PAGE --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mycomponent/index.json"
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore MyProject.Core/MyProject.Core.sln
    - name: Build against errors
      run: dotnet build BDInfo.Core/BDInfo.Core.sln --no-restore     
    - name: Create self-contained binary for MyProject
      run: dotnet publish MyProject.Core/MyProject/MyProject.csproj -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained
    - name: Create self-contained binary for BDExtractor
      run: dotnet publish MyProject.Core/BDExtractor/BDExtractor.csproj -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained
      
    - name: MyProject Zip Release
      # You may pin to the exact commit or the version.
      # uses: TheDoctor0/zip-release@591e9b128012d3328db6043d0d0266c3ac27f9b5
      uses: TheDoctor0/zip-release@0.6.1
      with:
        # Filename for archive
        filename: MyProject_linux_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        # Base path for archive files
        path: .
        # Working directory before zipping
        directory: MyProject.Core/MyProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/
        # List of excluded files / directories
        #exclusions: # optional, default is 
        # Tool to use for archiving
        type: zip
        
    - name: MyExtractor ZIP release
      uses: TheDoctor0/zip-release@0.6.1
      with:
        # Filename for archive
        filename: MyExtractor_linux_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        # Base path for archive files
        path: .
        # Working directory before zipping
        directory: MyProject.Core/MyExtractor/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/
        # List of excluded files / directories
        #exclusions: # optional, default is 
        # Tool to use for archiving
        type: zip
        
    - name: Create Release
      id: create_release
      uses: actions/create-release@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        tag_name: linux-${{ env.version }}
        release_name: Release Linux x64 ${{ env.version }}
        draft: false
        prerelease: false
        
    - name: Upload MyProject
      id: upload-release-asset-MyProject
      uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }} # This pulls from the CREATE RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
        asset_path: MyProject.Core/MyProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/MyProject_linux_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        asset_name: MyProject_linux_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        asset_content_type: application/zip
        
    - name: Upload MyExtractor
      id: upload-release-asset-MyExtractor
      uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }} # This pulls from the CREATE RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
        asset_path: MyProject.Core/MyExtractor/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/MyExtractor_linux_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        asset_name: MyExtractor_linux_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        asset_content_type: application/zip


  build_windows:

    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: [build_linux]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore MyProject.Core/MyProject.Core.sln
    - name: Build against errors
      run: dotnet build MyProject.Core/MyProject.Core.sln --no-restore     
    - name: Create self-contained binary for MyProject
      run: dotnet publish MyProject.Core/MyProject/MyProject.csproj -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained
    - name: Create self-contained binary for MyExtractor
      run: dotnet publish MyProject.Core/MyExtractor/MyExtractor.csproj -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained
      
    - name: MyProject Zip Release
      # You may pin to the exact commit or the version.
      # uses: TheDoctor0/zip-release@591e9b128012d3328db6043d0d0266c3ac27f9b5
      uses: TheDoctor0/zip-release@0.6.1
      with:
        # Filename for archive
        filename: MyProject_win_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        # Base path for archive files
        path: .
        # Working directory before zipping
        directory: MyProject.Core/MyProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/win-x64/publish/
        # List of excluded files / directories
        #exclusions: # optional, default is 
        # Tool to use for archiving
        type: zip
        
    - name: MyExtractor ZIP release
      uses: TheDoctor0/zip-release@0.6.1
      with:
        # Filename for archive
        filename: MyExtractor_win_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        # Base path for archive files
        path: .
        # Working directory before zipping
        directory: MyProject.Core/MyExtractor/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/win-x64/publish/
        # List of excluded files / directories
        #exclusions: # optional, default is 
        # Tool to use for archiving
        type: zip
        
    - name: Create Release
      id: create_release
      uses: actions/create-release@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        tag_name: win-${{ env.version }}
        release_name: Release Windows x64 ${{ env.version }}
        draft: false
        prerelease: false
        
    - name: Upload MyProject
      id: upload-release-asset-MyProject
      uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }} # This pulls from the CREATE RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
        asset_path: MyProject.Core/MyProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/win-x64/publish/MyProject_win_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        asset_name: MyProject_win_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        asset_content_type: application/zip
        
    - name: Upload MyExtractor
      id: upload-release-asset-MyExtractor
      uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }} # This pulls from the CREATE RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
        asset_path: MyProject.Core/MyExtractor/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/win-x64/publish/MyExtractor_win_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        asset_name: MyExtractor_win_v${{ env.version }}.zip
        asset_content_type: application/zip
```

The problem is that Github removes every time my PAT token when try to run workflow in order to restore packages.

What should do ?

Comment: Did you try adding the PAT as a repository secret to avoid exposing it in your code? You shouldn't hardcode this king of information in your files, that's probably why Github removes it everytime (as they might identify it with the gh_ prefix).

Comment: I tried to add it and use `${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}` but I got error that encryption is not supported on non-windows platform

Comment: First time I'm hearing about this one. For what I checked, it might be related to this: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1851